# How to access data from PHP object array

Tags: php, arrays, object, fitbit, temboo

I'm getting this object array as a response from the temboo fitbit api. This is the `print_r($result)` output:

```
Fitbit_Statistics_GetTimeSeriesByDateRange_Results Object ( [outputArray:protected] => Array ( [Response] => {"activities-log-steps":[{"dateTime":"2015-12-30","value":"129"}]} ) [lowercaseKeyMap:protected] => Array ( [response] => Response ) )
```

How do I access the `value` attribute of this object?

Comment: Well, this is `protected`, is there a `get` method? Also, did you try anything?

Comment: I found that temboo has methods to get the json: getTimeSeriesByDateRangeResults->getResponse()

Answer (score 1):

I found that temboo has methods to access the results:

```
getTimeSeriesByDateRangeResults->getResponse()
```

Comment: +1 https://github.com/temboo/php-examples/blob/master/FacebookMealsApp/php-sdk/src/library/temboo.fitbit.php#L3368

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/temboo/php-examples/blob/master/FacebookMealsApp/php-sdk/src/library/temboo.fitbit.php#L3368

Just do

```
$result->getResponse();
```